# How to create multi column drop-down using React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to create a multicolumn dropdown where I can display the name and its description in a single row. 
But When I will select the dropdown list it should display column 1 value as the selected value.  Please refer to the attached Image. And I am clueless about where to start.
[image: Need to create a dropdown similar to this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we achieved this using fluent UI customization dropdown.

```
 import * as React from 'react';
   import { Dropdown, Stack } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';
    import _ from 'lodash';

const onRenderOption = item => {
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style={{ width: 150 }}>{item.text}</td>
          <td style={{ width: 50 }} />
          <td title={item.description}>
            {_.get(item, 'description', '').length > 60
              ? `${item.description.substring(0, 55)}...`
              : item.description}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

export const MultiComboBox = props => (
  <Stack style={{ paddingTop: 16 }}>
    <Dropdown
      title={props.title}
      placeholder="any"
      label={props.label}
      options={props.options}
      selectedKey={props.value}
      dropdownWidth={600}
      onRenderLabel={props.selectedValue}
      onChange={(action, item) => props.onChange(item)}
      onRenderOption={onRenderOption}
    />
  </Stack>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used react as a tag, a simple solution using React can be:-

`list = [{country:"India",description:"Great"},{country:"USA",description:"Great"}]`

```
const [selectedCountry,setCountry] =useState(null)
<DropDown>
    <DropDownHeading>
    {selectedCountry?selectedCountry:Choose Country}
    </DropDownHeading>

    <DropDownMenu>
    list.map(listItem=><DropDownItem listItem={listItem} onClick={()=>setCountry(listItem.country)}/>)
    </DropDownMenu>
    </DropDown>
```

Your DropDownItem's JSX can be :-

```
<div>
<div><span>{country}</span></div>
<div><span>{description}</span></div>
</div>
```